# *ngFor does not display data

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I am writing my angular2 application.
I have service which fetches data from database and dashboard.component.html which uses the service to display fetched data.

myService:

```
detailedInfo(rownum:number){
    const url='/project/users';
    return this.http.get(`${url}/${rownum}`).pipe(map((data:any)=>data));
}
```

dashboard.component.ts:

```
resultDetails:any[]=[];

checkInformation(rownum:number) {
    console.log("Details are called");
    this.myService.detailedInfo(rownum).subscribe(
        data=> {
            console.log("we got:",data);
            this.resultDetails=data;
            console.log("length of details:"+this.resultDetails.length); 
        },
        error => {
            console.log("Error",error);
        }
    );
}
```

dashboard.component.html:

```
<i (click)="checkInformation(somenumber)"></i>
<table>
    <tr  *ngFor="let res of resultDetails">
        <td >result
           <p>any text</p>
        </td>
        <td>{{res.rownumber}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

`console.log` prints the correct result, but  displays nothing. How can I solve the problem? thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add what the data looks like

Comment: What does `console.log("we got:",data);` output

Comment: @mahval prints the data from array correctly

Comment: I think we are asking what the response looks like, show the JSON. You can make an edit to your question

Comment: If it is a object you can user keyvalue pipe like this <div *ngFor="data of datas | keyvalue;"> {{data | json}}  </div>

Comment: @T.S To formulate it differently: If your console.log prints data correctly, then `<td>{{res | json}}</td>` should at least show something. Try that. What does it show in the HTML?

Comment: @T.S: Please try and use `console.log("we got:",data);
  this.resultDetails=data as any;`.

Comment: there is an extra `tr` closing tag may be that's the issue.

Answer (score 1):

the issue is with the wrong html

```
  <i (click)="checkInformation(somenumber)"></i>
<table>

    <tr  *ngFor="let res of resultDetails">
        <td >result
           <p>any text</p>
        </td>
        <td>{{res.rownumber}}</td>
    </tr>

    </tr> <!-- this is extra tr remoe it 

</table>
```

remove extra tr

Comment: I thought it was a typo in the question and had it edited! xD